# Spiral traversing in matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, traversal

I was trying to solve the spiral traversing question but getting 2 errors in my code I don't know what does the error mean?

```
spiralmatrix.cpp:48:21: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘int (*)[100]’
   48 |         spiralprint(input,row,col);
      |                     ^~~~~
      |                     |
      |                     int**
spiralmatrix.cpp:4:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void spiralprint(int (*)[100], int, int)’
    4 | void spiralprint (int input[][100], int row ,int col)
      |                   ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My  funtion is :

```
void spiralprint (int input[][100], int row ,int col)
{
    int rs=0,cs=0,re=row-1,ce=col-1,count=0;
   
    while( count != row*col){
      for(int i =cs;i<ce;i++){
          cout<< input[rs][i]<<" ";
          count++;
      }
      rs++;
      for(int i=rs;i<=re;i++){
          cout<<input[i][ce]<<" ";
          count++;
      }
      ce--;
      for(int i=ce;i>=cs;i--){
          cout<<input[re][i]<<" ";
          count++;
      }
      re--;
       for(int i=re;i>=rs;i--){
          cout<<input[i][cs]<<" ";
          count++;
      }
      cs++; 
    } 
}
```

Main function through which i am calling :

```
int main (){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int row,col;
        cin >> row>> col;
        int **input = new int *[row];
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            input[i]=new int[col];
            for(int j =0;j<col;j++){
                cin>>input[i][j];
            }

        }
        spiralprint(input,row,col);

        for(int i =0;i<row;i++){
            delete[] input[i];
        }
        delete[] input;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Been trying to solve it for a long time. First I was facing issue in passing argument  `declaration of ‘input’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first` but resolved it by passing `input[][100]` after that the code is not compiling

Comment: Are you constrained in what features of C++ you can use? Normally pointers are avoided because they do cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: Hint: `int**` as a type means `int**` as an argument type.

Comment: The error means you were misled to believe a pointer to a pointer is equivalent to an array of arrays; they're not.

Comment: I am not getting what you trying to say can you explain a bit more I am actually new to this concept @tadman

Comment: You need to match the types. Close enough does not really count. If you have an `int**` variable, then the natural fit is an `int**` argument, not `int[][100]` which is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the types. Close enough does not really count. If you have an `int**` variable, then the natural fit is an `int**` argument, not `int[][100]` which is incompatible.

The layout of `int[][100]` looks like an arbitrary number of `int[100]` sequences stored end-to-end in memory as a *contiguous* series.

The layout of `int**` looks like an array of **pointers** to individual sequences of 100 `int`. These are unlikely to be contiguous, it's safer to assume they're scattered randomly around your memory space.

You can't easily convert to and from these forms. If you're using `int**` you're basically stuck using it, but the good news is that you can still reference individual elements as `x[i][j]` as you would with `int[][100]`, it's just that the compiler emits different instructions to handle the different memory layout.

> Tip: Avoid `new[]` and C style arrays if you can. Use `std::vector` and try and keep your structures as "flat" as possible. Most 2D arrays can be treated as a 1D array with *emulation*, where you do the lookups like `a[x + y * h]` for a given `x,y` coordinate for a given `h,w` height/width.

Comment: Your explanation is very much clear to me. So I should go with a vector instead rather than an array? It won't work with arrays?

Comment: It will work with arrays, but `std::vector` is better in a number of respects, especially since you don't need to deal with memory management.

Comment: I will try it then Thank you